# Htaccess remove symbols from link

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove 2 symbols "?&" from link https://www.example.com/?& by redirect it to https://www.example.com/.
I tried this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "&" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [R=301,L]
```

It worked but it removed also any really QUERY like `https://www.example.com/?set=down&page=3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the **working** rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&$
RewriteRule (.*)  /? [R=301,L,NE]
```

You can test the same at [result](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=c3bdfead-7ec8-55a3-bf6f-9cf1429e92fb)

In this solution we have matched the `query string` such that it if `starts with & and ends afterwards` then only rewrite happens.

For urls like `https://www.example.com/?set=down&page=3` the **rewrite condition fails** and hence no redirection happens.